# How can I increment value of the variable when scroll reaches top of the div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have 5 div on the same page and the same class name="post". Also I got one variable name p = 1.

What I want to do is when I scroll div1, it should increase p value by +1 means p=2 now for div1.

Then if I scroll div2 , it should increase p value by +1 means p=2 now for div2. etc. If I scroll div2 again, p value must be p=3.

If I scroll div4, p value must be 2 and again if I scroll div1, p value was 2 last time. Now it must be 3.

But what really happening when I scroll div1, p becomes p=2. Then if I scroll any div p becomes p=3, if I scroll again it becomes p=4.

So I want to do is  when I scroll any divs in any order it should increase the value of 'p' separately according that div. In other word I just want to count how many times I scroll all 5 divs individually.

[Here is my JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/052xntw9/25), and the JS code follows:

```
$("window").load()
{
    $('.post').scrollTop($('.post').height())  
}



var p=1;
$('.post').scroll(function() {


        if($(this).scrollTop()==0)
        {
            p++;
            alert(p);


        }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api to save the data individually

```
$("window").load(){
    $('.post').scrollTop($('.post').height()).data('p',0); //initialize
}


$('.post').scroll(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.scrollTop() == 0){
        $this.data('p',$this.data('p') + 1); //increment
        alert($this.data('p'));
    }  
});
```

See working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/052xntw9/26/)

Comment: hey bruno it works ok but one question can I put .data('p',0) in $('.post').scroll(function() { .....} or before that. i don't want to put in $("window").load(){ ----} function

Comment: @user2668276 you can't put inside $('.post').scroll. because you would be overriding the value o p every time on scroll

Comment: then   in $(document).ready(function() { ---- }); or may be in $(function(){----- }); ??

Comment: sure! you can do $(function(){ $('.post').data('p',0) }); it's a good place to put it

Comment: one small question if($this.scrollTop() == 0) this if statement I want to change into if($this.scrollTop() == 200) but it not working.

Comment: @user2668276 if you console.log($this.scrollTop()) you'll see the values are discrete. you can do if($this.scrollTop() < 200) but you may get an unexpected result